# Image Rotation: adjusting width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I did some snooping around for this.  There were some solutions but I couldn't understand them properly.  I tried to implement the rotation matrix but I can't do it.  I have created a simple fiddle where on click image gets rotate 90deg (does not include my implementation because i dont understand how to do it).  Below is that simple code.  Can someone guide me or help me implement the rotation.  What i want is initially you have certain width and height.  When rotate 90deg the width becomes height and height becomes width, so the image stays within the div.

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/72nptzq5/)

```
<div><img id="rotate-image"></div> 
<span onClick="myFunction()">click<span>
```

js

```
function myFunction(){
$("#rotate-image").css("transform", "rotate(90deg):}
```

As you can see in fiddle once you click, the image turn 90deg.  But if you increase/decrease the divider between result and javascript section, the image gets bigger and smaller.  I want the image to stay within the div box and get smaller based on the width of the div box.

Hope this doesn't confuse anyone. Need to rotate image (normal,90,180,270, back to normal)

Comment: Have you found a way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/72nptzq5/6/

CSS

```
.parent{
    width: 70%;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
#rotate-image{
    max-width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.table-cell{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <img id="rotate-image" src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/254_apps/images/200x200.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<span onclick="myFunction()">click</span>
```

Comment: the only thing is, the image comes out of the div box if you increase or decrease the divider between js and result (or decrease the size of the page).  the image should fit the box based on the increase/decrease of div box even after rotation.  Just the way it does during normal look.  Hope this makes sense